# Stack with For behavior

Tags: java, stack

The result of this is 4 3 2 and i don't know why. How does the for works with stacks/queues/lists? I not looking fo better choices for this code (as i already know them) i just want to know how this one works.

```
class Stack_1 {
        public static void main(String [] args) {
          Stack s = new Stack();
          List l= new LinkedList();
          for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            s.add(i);
          for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
            s.push(l.remove(i));//this does nothing
          for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
            System.out.print(" "+ s.pop() );
       }
      }
```

Comment: `for` operates independently from data structures. You don't have anything in the `List` `l` (it's size is `0` therefore `i < l.size()` is never true), so your second loop does nothing. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It just an exercise where you are trying to get the output of it(i didn't make the code), which is (4 3 2), i don't know , as the second loop does nothing, why the output is not 4 3 2 1 0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in the last loop, it iterates 5 times since you are going from 0 to the size of the stack (If you are wondering about that, the first loop is the one that fills it up). In each iteration you call `pop` on the stack, which removes and returns the element on top. So before the loop your stack is `[4,3,2,1,0]` after the first iteration `[3,2,1,0]` then `[2,1,0]` and so on. In each iteration you also print the removed top value, that's why you are seeing it on the console. After your loop terminated your stack will be empty. Hope it helps.

Comment: I solved it, each time the loop pops a number the stack gets smaller so by the time i=2, 2 is printed and therefore the stack is [1,0] so when i=3 it is already bigger than the stack so the loop stops. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting observation. If you want your code to behave correctly try the following:

```
    Stack s = new Stack();
    List l= new LinkedList();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      s.add(i);
    for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
      s.push(l.remove(i));//this does nothing
    int stackSize = s.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < stackSize; i++)
      System.out.print(" "+ s.pop() );
```

You want your last loop to run as many times as there are elements in your Stack; however, the Stack size is constantly changing by using pop(). Hope this helps.